# aws cli to list lambda applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, list, aws-lambda, aws-cli

Very simple question -- how to list aws lambda applications using cli?

I'm following:

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.1.29/reference/deploy/list-applications.html#examples

> **To get information about applications**
>
> The following `list-applications` example displays information about all applications that are associated with the user's AWS account.
>
> ```
> aws deploy list-applications
> ```

And this is what I get:

```
$ aws deploy list-applications
applications: []
```

However, I have many aws lambda applications:

[image]

how to list them using cli?

**UPDATE:**

I'm aware of the `aws lambda list-functions` command, however, it is not the ~functions~ but the ***applications*** that I need to list (as functions and the applications are named *differently*):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
aws lambda list-functions
```

This query will list all the details about your lambda, to list only the FunctionNames, or FunctionArns, you have to use:

```
aws lambda list-functions --query 'Functions[].FunctionName'
aws lambda list-functions --query 'Functions[].FunctionArn'
```

You can also filter by region for this you can use for example:

```
aws lambda list-functions --region eu-west-2
```

---

`aws deploy list-applications` is used to list all of the applications in an AWS CodeDeploy deployment group.

---

#### Edit

> it is not the functions but the applications that I need to list.

This is not possible, there are no commands to list the lambda applications, because:

> An AWS Lambda application is a **combination of Lambda functions, event
> sources, and other resources that work together to perform tasks**. You
> can use AWS CloudFormation and other tools to collect your
> application's components into a single package that can be deployed
> and managed as one resource.

[AWS Lambda applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/deploying-lambda-apps.html)

---

In fact, you can get the name of your application from CloudFormation:

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks
```

but is it a good idea, I don't know ?!

Comment: @xpt oops, my miss read your question, check my edit

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`aws lambda list-functions`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.1.29/reference/lambda/list-functions.html) to list all functions.

`aws deploy list-applications` lists all CodeDeploy applications.

All aws-cli calls have the format `aws <service> <operation>`, e.g.

- `aws lambda list-functions` - AWS Lambda
- `aws deploy list-applications` - AWS CodeDeploy
- `aws s3 ls` - S3

You can view all available services here - https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.1.29/reference/index.html#available-services

Comment: Thanks but it is not the functions but the applications that I need to list. See my OP for the updates.